# Proof: Definition of Limits ($\pi$)

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow ∞}$ $x_n$ = $\pi$. I must prove (using the definition of limit) that there is an $n_0$ such that $x_n < 22/7$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

I've tried the usual method, but I'm stuck. How can I show this without the sequence $x_n$ being defined explicitly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\pi$, by definition this means that for any given $\varepsilon>0$, for some $N\in\Bbb N$ we have for $n>N$ $$|x_n-\pi|<\varepsilon.$$ Let $\varepsilon=22/7-\pi$. Now we can see that $$|x_n|\leq|x_n-\pi|+\pi<(22/7-\pi)+\pi=22/7.$$ This proves the claim.

Comment: Nice deduction. A simple one! +1

Comment: @BabakSorouh: Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\varepsilon = 22/7 - \pi$. Notice that $\varepsilon >0$ and use it in the definition of limit...

Answer (score 1):

Take

$$\epsilon:=\frac{22}{7}-\pi\Longrightarrow\,\,\exists\,\,N_\epsilon\in\Bbb N\,\,\,s.t.\,\,\,\forall\,\,n>N_\epsilon\;,\;\;|x_n-\pi|<\epsilon\ldots$$

Comment: so here, $n_0$ can be any integer $\geq$ $22/7 - \pi$?

Comment: Uh? Well, no....what that has to do with anything? In order to know what $\,n_0\,$ works (I don't know what for, though...), one ha to know the sequence, to begin with.

Comment: oh ok, I see where youre coming from, thanks

Answer (score 1):

First note that $\pi < \frac{22}{7}$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80).

Now suppose $x_n \to \pi$. Choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{22}{7} -\pi) > 0$. Then there exists some $N$ such that if $n \geq N$, then $|x_n-\pi| < \epsilon$. In particular, $x_n -\pi < \frac{1}{2} (\frac{22}{7} -\pi)$, or $x_n < \frac{1}{2} (\frac{22}{7} +\pi) < \frac{1}{2} (\frac{22}{7} +\frac{22}{7}) = \frac{22}{7}$ as required.